# I am not understanding how to use cache context

Tags: caching

In search result page I need to change url of title field based on permission assigned to  user .  If user has permission then show url 1 else show url 2 .

We need to cache all renderable array. I am creating

```
$data = [
  '#type' => 'link',
  ' #href' => $url, 
]
```

I am confused with cache context and cache tags.

Please suggest which one to use?

Answer (score 2):

Cache context - https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/cache-api/cache-contexts - is how the cached content varies. In your case you want it to vary - be different for - users based on if they have a permission or not. i.e. you want it to be cached one way if they have the permission, and another way if they don't have the permission. So you probably want `user.permissions:<your_permission>`.

Cache contexts need to be something Drupal can work out *before* it gets to the level where it's rendering content and etc so that's why you can have a context on `route` (cheap to inspect because Apache just gives it to you) but not `node` (expensive to vary on because to work out the node Drupal needs to run SQL) - because hopefully Drupal can just serve content out of cache before it even gets to the point of working out if the current `route` matches a `node` in the database or not.

Cache tags - https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/cache-api/cache-tags - are for what your cached data is *dependent* on. In your case, URL probably points to something right? So if it points to e.g. a node, your cache tag would be 
`node:<nid>`, and Drupal will know that if node *nid* ever changes it should delete those cache entries, because the URL might have changed.

You *shouldn't* just manually set the cache tag to `node:<nid>` though - the more generic way to do it is to use [addCacheableDependency](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21Renderer.php/function/Renderer%3A%3AaddCacheableDependency/8.2.x).

Comment: Great answer, BTW the context is already set as default, see core.services.yml: `renderer.config: required_cache_contexts: ['languages:language_interface', 'theme', 'user.permissions']`